# Excel-VBA "type mismatch" error when using Format() to convert Date to String

Tags: excel, vba, datetime-format, userform, type-mismatch

I am working on code that runs within a userform in Excel 2013. It is supposed to convert dates to string values to pass into text boxes within the form.

I have done this before and have never had any trouble with it. I am now getting a Runtime Error 13 "type mismatch" whenever I attempt to execute the following code:

```
Me.ListingDate.Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

The objective of this line is to format today's date and pass it to the textbox. I tried breaking it down into individual steps:

```
Dim MyDate As Date
Dim MyString As String

MyDate = Now()

MyString = Format(MyDate, "mm/dd/yy")

Me.ListingDate.Value = MyString
```

This still triggers a type mismatch error in the line where the `Format()` function is invoked on a date value.

I have run this code for over a year and never had any problems. There are several other forms in the file that use a similar syntax and it works.

Is it possible for a userform to become corrupted and falsely generate a runtime error?  What other factors may be causing the error?

Comment: Do you have something else named `Format` or `Now`?

Comment: Your code runs fine in my Excel VBA window. It could be a corruption issue. Maybe try making a new Excel project and importing everything over from this one. I've done this with Access a number of times and it always seems to do the trick...maybe it'll work for you in Excel.

Comment: There is no object or variable in the project named `Format` or `Now`.  So it should not be an ambiguous reference problem.  I may try importing everything to a new file.  The fact that the code fails here and works in another module makes me suspect a corruption issue.

Comment: I tried exporting the entire userform to a clean project, and that did not appear to solve the issue.  It still throws a type mismatch just like before.  Any other ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: If you put the caret on the word `Format` and press `Shift+F2`, where does that take you? Have you tried inspecting `MyDate` in the watch window?